# Two Sockets for Only One Connection

Tags: java, sockets, instant-messaging

I am making an instant messenger in Java and I want to add the ability to send images as well as text. The first thing that came to mind was to make new Sockets and input and output streams. Firstly, will this work and is it good practice. Secondly, if this doesn't work then how does the receiving end of the message figure out if what it is receiving is an image or a String?

Comment: It'll work, but you'll have two connections, and it's probably not the best idea. You need to introduce some *metadata* into your data format to indicate what is a String and what is an image (and what is some future thing you've not thought of yet).

Comment: I din't think you want multiple sockets. Everything goes our the same tube. Two sockets won't grant you anything. Remember sockets are two-way pipes.

Comment: So currently I have a way of sending a code (aka an int) and a message (aka a string). I have tried to playing around with that so I send a code telling the receiving end, image coming through, then changing the message to just an Object, but it would only want to send the file path of the image. Also, I don't know how to tell if an Object is a String or a File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An output stream contains bytes, which you have to build into messages.  The reader knows which type of data you sent, because the sender will have to say which type of message it is sending.

e.g. if you write say "image" as a string you could assume that what follows it is an image.

Comment: Then how do I tell which type of Object it is in java?

Comment: @dsiegler19 it is the type you said it was when you wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you're not transmitting Strings or Images, you're exchanging *Messages*. A message should have a content or message type associated with it.

Comment: Thank you I got it, after for some reason having completely messed up a .substring somewhere in the code, causing it to crash a lot. I used the instanceof keyword.

Comment: It sounds like you're using Java serialization to send messages back and forth. While this will work and is fine for a test project, if you want to be robust, you really should define a separate serialization format that you have control over, e.g. JSON or XML messages. This will help with future expansions (remember to include a message type revision number in the messages)